# Android Fade in Fade out Together

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make blinking image button.

I was thinking about to use fade-in and fade-out , but I cant use it together at 1 Image Button. Following code blinks only once:

```
Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); 
fadeIn.setDuration(1000);

Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); 
fadeOut.setStartOffset(1000);
fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); 
animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
this.setAnimation(animation);`
```

Comment: Read about [`AnimationListener.onAnimationEnd`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationEnd%28android.view.animation.Animation%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this:

`AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false);
...
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
this.setAnimation(animation);`

Obviously, adjust the count as needed.

Comment: as you said to NameSpace Animation.Restart works great thank you sir